# Cant display timeframe in alert

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

alertcondition(inBar, title='IOB: Inside Bar', message='{{ticker}}, 1, {{timeframe.period}}')
I cant seem to get timeframe.period to display stuff like 1m, 5m, 15m, 240m etc.. it just comes out as string "timeframe.period".

funny thing ticker is actually from "syminfo.ticker" but i neednt reference syminfo for some reason.
I tried the same logic by omitting timeframe... ("period") but it doesnt work. Trying "timeframe" alone doesnt work either.

I did not define any of the 2 in custom variables either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using {{interval}} for alert condition. There are not a lot of options for alertcondition to use variable strings. alert() is far more versatile, but for to find more info on placeholders for alertcondition, visit this [URL](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000531021)